# ELKI - How get clusters from elki's cluster object order file?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, elki, optics-algorithm

Running on ELKI the OPTICS and DeLiClu algorithms I get only the cluster object order file as result. How can I get the clusters list and the mapping among points and the respective cluster?

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, you should accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OPTICS class does *not* (by design) produce clusters.

Instead, it produces the **cluster order** as defined by OPTICS.

If you want to extract partitions from the cluster order, please use the class `OPTICSXi`, which implements the main extraction method (adding the xi parameter) discussed in the OPTICS paper. This method can be used with either OPTICS or DeLiClu.

There are other alternatives to extract such partitions, but they have not yet been contributed to ELKI.